# Replace one Voltage Regulator by two coexisting regulators (NOT in "parallel")

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

First of all, I know that I cannot simply parallel two voltage regulators to double my output power. At least not without actions to keep the two regulators "balanced" as was discussed here:

[2 Voltage regulator wired together to produce higher amperage possible?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12801/2-voltage-regulator-wired-together-to-produce-higher-amperage-possible)

Also, I want to use a synchronous step-down converter with integrated FETs, so I know no way of adding such a "balancing circuit" because there is no easy way of sensing the currents ofthe two ICs.

Now to my question: Suppose (just an example) that I need 5 amps at 3.3V, is there any flaw with just using 2 regulators with 2 x 2.5A that are NOT in parallel, but only with the same GND connection supplying different 3V3 regions on the target PCB? So the idea is, power the core components like processor and near peripherals with the rails of one of the regulators and the rest of the 3V3 peripherals with the rail of the second regulator.

Of course, then there is the case that e.g. peripheral A and the processor are powered from two "different" power rails, which could have a few percent of difference in there nominal output voltage. But even though, I don´t think that there is a problem with "crossing currents".

My thoughts so far:
Example 1: Processor is supplied with 3.3V and its pin drives an input of peripheral 2 which is supplied with only 3.2V. There is no problem with this as long as peripheral 2 can accept input voltages that are 0.1V higher than the supply (which most devices accept! Of course the tolaerance level has to be greater because both rails have some ripple...)

Can you tell me if there is any flaw in this thought and am I missing something else to be considered?

Comment: Regulators can share the same ground, and you can have many regulators supplying different loads sharing that ground. But "crossing currents" (makes me think of ghostbusters lol) can be a problem if you have fast switching devices and you get conducted noise or interference.

Comment: That´s also what I have been thinking about but If two Regulators share the same Ground, I think that a current driven by regulator 1 can use "GND2" as well as "GND1" (since they are the same) to return to. So there should be no "crossing currents" - at least not more than one can get due to the typical problems with ground traces/planes (non zero inductance and resistance and therefore induced voltages), right?

Comment: 'crossing currents' is not really a thing. Its really noise and interference and the higher the frequency and power a load has the more that load may interfere with another load. I mean its only a problem when you start going higher than 3-10MHz, but also hard switching heavy currents can cause problems too, but these things are dealt with by understanding what loads you are dealing with and filtering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*...I need 5 amps at 3.3V, is there any flaw with just using 2 regulators with 2 x 2.5A that are NOT in parallel, but only with the same GND connection supplying different 3V3 regions on the target PCB?*

Yes, that is possible. **But** don't "see" it as 2 regulators supplying 5 A bit see it as 2 regulators each supplying up to 2.5 A, because that's what it is. As long as you do not exceed the 2.5 A **per supply domain** you will be fine. This is what is done on many PC motherboards. Count the number of inductors near the CPU, each one is supplying a different supply domain.

If you keep the supply voltages roughly the same value (less than 100 mV difference) then I would expect no problems on the domain crossings.

On a PC motherboard the domains will have different voltages and then levelshifters are needed, most of these are present on the CPU but some can be external as well.

Comment: I wonder also, if there will be EMC troubles when doing so, but I think as the GND should be "as good" as with one regulator (since connected right at the two regulators), there should be no impact concerning EMC?

Comment: I think for EMC it is best to keep the ground connections short so the best is one groundplane for all domains. It is difficult to predict EMC troubles at this stage it depends on many other things. Just keep the loops of high frequency currents (like in the switched mode regulators) as short as possible. Look at other good designs, do the same and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is OK to do as you described, I have used similar schemes in several boards over the years.

Comment: **Warning** if rails come up or drop at slightly different times, check this won't affect  power-on-reset strategies, or cause connections across the power domains to drive excess currents into I/Os. Series resistors may be a sufficient fix for I/Os, group all dependent things like an FPGA and its programming ROM onto the same power domain.